# Falta traducir texto en preguntas eliminadas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Hoy ingrese a una pregunta que se eliminó, y vi que falta un texto por traducir. A continuación pongo una imagen del mismo.

[image: Texto sin traducir]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se ha corregido. Falta que se actualize la base de datos, pero los cambios ya fueron hechos.

Answer (score 0):

`Try a Google Search` debería decir `Intenta una búsqueda en google` y `Here are some similar questions that might be revelant` deberia ser `Aquí hay algunas preguntas que pudiesen ser relevantes`.

Eso sería una sugerencia